# Removing UIImageView From Button

Tags: ios, uiimageview

This code i use for the purpose

```
 if(editedImage !=nil)
{
    [selectionView1 removeFromSuperview];

    UIImageView *selectionView1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:editedImage.image];

    [_buttonScroll addSubview:selectionView1];
}

else{
[_buttonScroll addSubview:selectionView1];
}
```

i did in way when first time it executes then editedImage is nil so it goes in else then later on editedImage gets images like below

```
    -(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
      didFinishPickingImage : (UIImage *)image
                 editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{

      NSLog(@"%@",image);
  editedImage   = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: image];
    NSLog(@"%@",editedImage);
    // editedImage is UIImageView

    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

so it get filled and when second time my first code execute then editedImage is not null and it goes inside of if(editedImage !=nil) condition and for that now i want to delete old image which was on button and add this new image which i got from edited image

so the problem is old image is not getting removed what am i doing wrong can you please suggest me something

Comment: is _buttonScroll your UIButton ?

Comment: yes it is. its UIButton Bhargavi :)

Comment: I wonder what is the need of adding view in UIButton instead you should use setBackgroundImage or setImage property of button.

Comment: see this is what is difference between trainee and some experienced girl.as i have done this stupidity and going on this way so what can be the solution?

Comment: What i understand is you want to pick one image from picker and set it on button right ?

Comment: yes its like image was already there which user selected before but now he is in another view and he dont like that image he want to change it so thats why image was there but now need to remove it im able to add new image there but i want to remove old image i just dont want to  override it so thats why this all things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
      didFinishPickingImage : (UIImage *)image
                 editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{

    [_buttonScroll setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

try this simply :)

Comment: old image will get removed ? or we are just overriding it ?

Comment: Yes we are just overriding it. Have you tried it ? Is that working for you ?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
      didFinishPickingImage : (UIImage *)image
                 editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{

  NSLog(@"%@",image);
  if(editedImage)
     [editedImage removeFromSuperview];

  editedImage   = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: image];
    NSLog(@"%@",editedImage);
    // editedImage is UIImageView

    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: why you are removing editedImage from superview? should we not remove selectionView1 from superview because that is what on that button which appears?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is keep track of the image that you are adding. You can either keep a property variable to the image that is being added, but a better option is to just set the tag of the image that gets added. If you change your first if statement to as follows:

```
//set a tag value to use (defined at the top of your file outside the @implementation)
#define PREVIOUS_VIEW_TAG 999

if(editedImage !=nil)
{
    UIView* previousImageView = [_buttonScroll viewWithTag:PREVIOUS_VIEW_TAG];
    [previousImageView removeFromSuperview];

    UIImageView *selectionView1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:editedImage.image];
    selectionView1.tag = PREVIOUS_VIEW_TAG;

    [_buttonScroll addSubview:selectionView1];
}

else{
    selectionView1.tag = PREVIOUS_VIEW_TAG;
    [_buttonScroll addSubview:selectionView1];
}
```

This should let you keep track of the view that you are adding. The value of the PREVIOUS_VIEW_TAG could be anything, I just picked 999.

Also keeping in mind what @Bhargavi suggested, using [_buttonScroll setBackgroundImage:selectionView1] and then removing with [_buttonScroll setBackgroundImage:nil]; (or just override by setting the new backgroundImage) would also work. However, to specifically answer your question, perhaps consider keeping track of the view with a tag.

Comment: ah, I see @Bhargavi submitted an answer now. It is certainly the better way to deal with images and buttons.

Comment: thanks for this nice answer  i want to give up vote but i dont have that privilege :( thank you so much